# Service in Android to detect internet availability and stop user if not available without writing code on each activity

Tags: android, android-service, android-intentservice, android-service-binding

I want to write a service which can check the availability of the internet connection in android. If the internet is not available then it should show some popup box with some message and stop to user from performing any operation. This service must start when i store the application and we should not write the separate code on each activity. I wrote a service to detect the internet availability but i was not able to write the code to show popup  and stop to user in case of non availability of internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

I guess i got my answer.

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/android-internet-connection-status-network-change/

If you want to build like this kind of functionality then please visit above link. We don't need to build any service for this. We can do the same by broadcast receiver.